# Count number of conditional formatted cells using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of conditional formatted cells in a row.

This function however returns the total number of cells, even those that did not pass the conditional formatting criteria:

```
Public Function CountColour(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In pRange1    
    If rng.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = pRange2.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color Then
        CountColour = CountColour + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Any idea?

It is a school test where the number of right answers needs to be calculated.

[image: school test]

Comment: `rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` and `pRange2.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: ^ Except don't use this as a UDF in a sheet, it won't work, see the [`DisplayFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat) docs.

Comment: ^^ The only way to count conditional formatting with a UDF from the worksheet is to count the criteria that causes the format in the first place.

Comment: ^^^ I don't have anything else to comment but felt like putting 3 carets to start a trend.

Comment: Yes, by using DisplayFormat I do get the #VALUE! error. So there is no way to do this?
The criteria is a string comparison between a cell and the selected cells.

Comment: Then count those and not the display color

Comment: `CountColour = Application.Countif(pRange1,pRange2)` where `pRange2` is the range with the string.

Comment: In fact I would skip the whole UDF and just use COUNTIF()

Comment: How do you want to handle when there are multiple criteria involved?

Comment: Thanks Scott, but the conditional formatting is applied vertically, and I need to summarize the affected cells horizontally. I have updated my post with a picture.

Comment: Put this in H5 `=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$3:$G$3 = $E5:$G5))` and copy down.

Comment: Or:  `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($E$3:$G$3,$E5:$G5))` and copy down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip trying to count the conitional formatting and count the condition:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($E$3:$G$3=$E5:$G5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution!